# Draw road network given a graph with lanes information

Tags: python, matlab, openstreetmap, matlab-figure

I'm currently working on reconstructing road networks using data from OpenStreetMaps. Specifically, I've created an undirected graph in which Nodes represent road waypoints, and Edges represent road segments. Each Node contains its (x, y) position, and each Edge stores information about the number of lanes.

In other words, I'm trying to draw the road network in RED given the undirected graph in BLACK.
[image: Problem description]

I'm interested in finding out if there are any open-source or readily available algorithms to tackle this problem. The complexity of this task can grow rapidly when attempting to generalize the solution, so any guidance or existing algorithms that can be applied to this scenario would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

What I tried:
I tried to implement simple logics in matlab: consider one way (unique number of lanes), create artificial points for each node based on the number of lanes (red points in the figure), then join them using spline.
In the figure, a 2-lanes road divides into 2 1-lane roads.
[image: What I tried]
Clearly when we have road joining / junctions this architecture does not work anymore. Also I think using Graphs we can generalize the job more easily.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.